# How to update libreoffice 4.0 to 4.2

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

How would I update libreoffice 4.0 to 4.2, I tried the default `apt-get update' and 'upgrade` but It didn't detect that there is a new version yet. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add the repo then do a distribution upgrade.

Repo; http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu

The easiest way is to run these commands in a terminal (CLI) one after the other;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

When there is a new version Update Manager will say some packages are held back. The key is to do a distribution upgrade via CLI.